# Filter log streams in aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there anyway to filter the log streams with patterns using the CloudWatch console?

For example, I have the following log streams in a log group - 
Log Group:

> '/var/prod/logs'.

Log Streams:

> /prod/[node_instance_id]/nginx_access
>   /prod/[node_instance_id]/nginx_error

I have a multi-node environment with auto scaling etc.  So the log streams can be quite messy - here is an example of what I see in the log streams.

> /prod/1a2b3c4d5e/nginx_access
>    /prod/1a2b3c4d5e/nginx_error
>    /prod/1b2b3c4d5e/nginx_access
>    /prod/1b2b3c4d5e/nginx_error
>    /prod/1c2b3c4d5e/nginx_access
>    /prod/1c2b3c4d5e/nginx_error

I am trying to filter the log streams to be all 'nginx_access' only.  But from the console, it looks like I can only specify the prefix.  Is there anyway that I could filter log streams using something like '*nginx_access'?

Answer (score 3):

The [DescribeLogStreams API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLogStreams.html) only supports filtering by prefix, and the console is listing your log streams with that API. It is not possible to filter by something other than a prefix.

The best practice in your case would be to use 2 log groups, one for each type:

- /var/prod/nginx_access
- /var/prod/nginx_error

That way you can navigate to your logs by first choosing the appropriate log group, and then searching for the instance id with the prefix filter.

Comment: Thanks for the info Daniel!  It's useful to know that the console is actually making used of this API calls.  Just out of curiosity, This [FilterLogEvents API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html) seems to be what I am looking for.  Do you know if the console is making used of this API at all?

Comment: @RayT - Not when listing log streams. The console uses DescribeLogStreams for that. FilterLogEvents is used for searching within the log streams or log groups.

Comment: I'm wondering how can I actually search by "prefix" from CloudWatch console. I'm only able to search the whole log group like this: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/batch/job;
or the particular stream: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/batch/job;stream=/my-app/...
But I need to use the whole stream name - I'd like to use just a prefix like "/my-app/*"